Cannot find dotnet version when deploying flex consumption function app with github actions
I am attempting to deploy a .Net 8 function app to a flex consumption plan on our Azure subscription. However, when I run the action, after the build, I get the error "Error: Couldn't detect a version for the platform 'dotnet' in the repo."
Github failure log
name: Deploy DotNet project to Azure Function App

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME: 'function app name'   
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'       
  DOTNET_VERSION: '8.0.x'                   

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest # For Linux, use ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev
    steps:
    - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    # If you want to use Azure RBAC instead of Publish Profile, then uncomment the task below
    # - name: 'Login via Azure CLI'
    #   uses: azure/login@v1
    #   with:
    #     creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_RBAC_CREDENTIALS }} # set up AZURE_RBAC_CREDENTIALS secrets in your repository

    - name: Setup DotNet ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }} Environment
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}

    - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Dotnet'
      shell: pwsh
      run: |
        pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
        dotnet build --configuration Release --output ./output
        popd

    - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
      id: fa
      with:
        sku: flexconsumption
        remote-build: true
        scm-do-build-during-deployment: false
        enable-oryx-build: false
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME }}
        package: '${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/output'

I have declared the dotnet version as a variable in the workflow file, and I have checked the solution and the .csproj file and they include the dotnet version as well.

I believe, currently only two deployment options are available for Flex consumption plan, refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/flex-consumption-how-to?tabs=azure-cli%2Ccore-tools&pivots=programming-language-csharp#deploy-your-code-project. You can consider using any of the given tool


Currently Flex Consumption plan is in Preview and under development phase and by looking at the MS Doc, I believe for now you can deploy the functions to Flex Consumption plan using either visual studio code or Core Tools.
I have created a workflow using the build in template present in GitHub Actions for Azure function app and added a secret AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE  in secrets and variables tab.

name: Deploy DotNet project to Azure Function App

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME: 'afreen-fa'   
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'       
  DOTNET_VERSION: '8.0.x'                   

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  # For ubuntu-latest, use windows-latest 
    environment: dev
    steps:
    - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Setup DotNet ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }} Environment
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}

    - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Dotnet'
      shell: pwsh # For Linux, use bash
      run: |
        pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
        dotnet build --configuration Release --output ./output
        popd
    - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
      id: fa
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME }}
        package: '${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/output'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}


Unfortunately, this code will fail with 404 error while deploying to Flex Consumption function app because a Flex Consumption app expects publish URI with the zip file to be scm_url + /api/publish whereas it is using scm_url + /api/zipdeploy.




Product team is working on the fix which you can refer from this github issue.
I have deployed my function to Flex consumption function app successfully using visual studio code. So, I would suggest you to use Visual studio code or Core Tools for the time being.




This is true. Despite the documentation to the Github Action found at: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-functions-action, the only way I found to successfully deploy to a Flex consumption app is to use VS Code and Core tools. Hopefully this gets fixed soon.
